# slow embedded database processing with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, h2, embedded-database

I use h2 database in embedded mode, also I use hibernate to access it. That is my spring config I am using to initialize hibernate:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>classname1</value>
            <value>classname2</value>
            <value>classname3</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

when I try insert data database works very, very slow and I have very huge IO stream (as fast as hard drive is able). I think database is opened and closed every time when

```
getHibernateTemplate().save(question);
```

is called. What is interesting, if I change connection string to use standalone server this problem disappears and all works nice.

What is wrong with my config for embedded databases?

**UPD**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:C:\temp\data.db" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Comment: How does your `dataSource` look like? Do you use a connection pool and what are the configuration parameters?

Comment: @benjamin-muschko I have added config for datasource

Comment: You you append `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1` to the database URL? I don't know Spring too well, but if it's a `DriverManagerDataSource`, why don't you just use `org.h2.Driver`?

Comment: Thank you for DB_CLOSE_DELAY, I will try it and write results here. I think org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource internally uses org.h2.Driver, so it's not a big difference.

Comment: I have added DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 and no more unnecessary openings and closings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) opens and closes a connection whenever you request one.

From the JavaDoc:

> NOTE: This class is not an actual
>   connection pool; it does not actually
>   pool Connections. It just serves as
>   simple replacement for a full-blown
>   connection pool, implementing the same
>   standard interface, but creating new
>   Connections on every call.

For production environments it's highly recommended that you use a connection pool which opens a limited number of connections up-front and pools them for usage. For your `dataSource` I'd say use [Apache's Jakarta Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). [This example](http://longlog.wordpress.com/2007/01/22/spring-dbcp/) shows how you can set up your `dataSource` to use DBCP. Using a connection pool will definitely reduce the time spend to query the database and will most certainly solve your problem.